# Proving truth or falsity of system of inequalities

Tags: inequality

I am stuck on this paper I am studying.

Prove or disprove that the system of inequalities

$ a, b, d, e, f, g, h, i > 0 $

$ a + e - i > 0 $

$ ae - ai - bd - ei - fh > 0 $

$- aei - hfa + bdi - gbf > 0 $

is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two inequalities are inconsistent under the assumption that all the variables are positive (even ignoring $a+e-i>0$). If the last two inequalities were both true, then the last inequality plus $i$ times the second-to-last inequality would also be true; but this equals
$$
(- aei - hfa + bdi - gbf)+i(ae - ai - bd - ei - fh)= - hfa - gbf- ai^2 - ei^2 - fhi>0,
$$
which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Wow. What an elegant solution!


What was your thinking process that led to multiplying the second inequality by i? I am asking because I still have to prove several similar inequalities.

Comment: Good question! Looking at the last two inequalities, I noted that there was only one positive term in each one. Then I noticed that the positive term in each one was matched by a similar negative term in the other one (e.g., $ae$ was matched by $-iae$). Something had to give....

Comment: Very insightful! You're a great help. Thank you.